# Не работает Contact form 7, не отправляются письма

Tags: wordpress, safari, contact-form7

В Safari не отправляются письма через Contact Form 7 и не срабатывает валидация данных, в остальных браузерах все в порядке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы  плагин Contact form 7 снова заработал у пользователей  Safari, нужно отключить использование технологии Ajax.

Вот этот код нужно добавить в functions.php

```
function wpcf7_load_js_not_safari11() {
global $is_safari;
if($is_safari) {
  return false;
} else {
  return true;
}
}
add_filter( ‘wpcf7_load_js’, ‘wpcf7_load_js_not_safari11’ );
```

Comment: Если отключить аякс, то будет рефреш страницы и др побочные эффекты. К тому же это лечение последствий, а не причин  Лечи браузер.

Answer (score 0):

по пробуйте другой плагин. например:Ninja Forms. Раньше я тоже пользовалась Contact Form 7 и по истечению некоторого времени я заметила его не стабильность.